# Ранжирование вариационного ряда

Tags: c++, математика, статистика

столкнулся с проблемой ранжирования вариационного ряда, попытался реализовать алгоритм:

- Расставляем каждому элементу ряда начальный ранг как его номер по порядку(в отсортированном контейнере)
- Если находим встречающиеся несколько раз элементы, суммируем их ранги(которые поставили изначально) и делим на количество повторов. Собственно, вот функция, которая возвращает сумму рангов каждой из выборок, но ранжирование производится почему то неверно, хотя на мой взгляд, логика правильная.

  ```
   inline std::pair<double, double> getRank(const std::vector<std::pair<double, int> >& a) {
   std::vector<double> _rank(a.size());
   double rankX = 0., rankY = 0.;
   int _count = 1;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
       _rank[i] = _count;
       ++_count;
   }
   double qq = 1.;
   double ranklist = 0.;
   int it, it_1;
   std::pair<double, int> is_find;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; ++i) {
       if (a[i].first == a[i + 1].first) {
           is_find = { a[i].first, a[i].second };
           ++qq;
           ranklist += _rank[i];
       }
       else {
           it = -1 * std::distance(std::lower_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), is_find), a.begin());
           it_1 = -1 * std::distance(std::upper_bound(a.begin(), a.end(), is_find), a.begin());
           for (int i = it; i < it_1 - 1; ++i) {
               _rank[i] = ranklist / qq;
           }
       qq = 1.;
       ranklist = 0.;
       }
   }
   for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
       if (a[i].second == 1) rankX += _rank[i];
       else if (a[i].second == 2) rankY += _rank[i];
   }
   cout << rankX << " " << rankY << endl;
   return std::make_pair(rankX, rankY);
  }
  ```

Например, такой тест(1 - принадлежность выборке 1, 2 - принадлежность выборке 2):

```
125 1
126 1
127 1
127 1
128 1
130 1
131 1
131 1
133 1
135 1
137 1
137 1
137 1
137 1
119 2
121 2
123 2
124 2
125 2
129 2
129 2
129 2
129 2
130 2
130 2
131 2
```

СуммаX = 234.5, СуммаY = 116.5

Мой вывод СуммаX = 236, СуммаY = 106.333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас в ряду 14+12=26 различных чисел, то сумма их рангов должна быть 26*27/2= 351.
Сумма рангов первых 14 элементов рангов - 105.

Сумма рангов оставшихся 12 элементов - 246.

Что означают приведенные вами ряды и суммы -  неведомо.

P.S. По просьбе ТС прикладываю код подсчета рангов двух выборок с учетом повторений на Python. Изначально ДатаФрейм имеет два столбца - 'A' -  значения, 'B' -  метка класса.

```
df1=df.sort_values(['A']).reset_index()
df1['R']=df1.index+1
df1['R']=df1['R'].groupby([df1.A]).transform('mean')
in1=sum(list(df1.R[df1.B==1]))
in2=sum(list(df1.R[df1.B==2]))
```

Полученные значения сумм рангов

```
print(in1, in2)
234.5 116.5
```

Comment: С суммой рангов соглашусь, но ранжировать нужно в общем вариационном ряду. Мой пример сначала нужно отсортировать по первому ключу, соответственно, на вход уже приходит отсортированный вектор пар, а затем уже в нем расставляются ранги. Приведенная мной сумма считает сумму рангов, элементы которых принадлежат разным выборкам(отличаются по 2 ключу). СуммаX - выборка 1, СуммаY - выборка 2

Comment: Значения рангов для элементов "1" - 237, для элементов "2"-114. Считал с помощью Python. Там это занимает ровно четыре рядка.

Comment: А как вы обрабатывали одинаковые элементы?

Comment: Виноват, пересчитал.   Получил, для элементов "1" - 234.5, для элементов "2"-116.5.

Comment: Кстати, если все это делается для критерия  Манна-Уитни, то его результат для ваших данных: statistic=38.5, pvalue=0.009995631079976803

Comment: Сумма рангов мне тоже нужна для этого критерия, но я считаю по Z-stat, т.к. объем выборок больше 8

Comment: Можете выложить код для подсчета рангов у одинаковых элементов? Не уверен, пойму ли синтаксис python, но чтобы найти ошибку в логике своей программы этого должно хватить.

Comment: Код приложил к ответу выше. Надеюсь -  он вам поможет. Это код для полного подсчета рангов элементов первой и второй выборок с учетом повторений.